# Use typescript with react-intl

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using in mu application `react-intl`. And i have the next code:

```js
const intl = useIntl();
const test = makeTest(error, intl.formatMessage);

// call test in another file:

const run = (error: ApolloError, formatMessage): string => {
 ...
};
```

How you can see i use typescript in my react application, but i have a problem when i want to type the `formatMessage` from  `const run = (error: ApolloError, formatMessage): string`.
 I searched in different sources but i could't type that parameter, how to ype `formatMessage`?

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `useIntl` can be looked up either in an IDE or from the source code https://github.com/awoodworth/react-intl/blob/master/src/components/useIntl.ts

The type ends up being

```
import { MessageDescriptor } from 'react-intl';

const run = (error: ApolloError, formatMessage: (descriptor: MessageDescriptor) => string): string => {
 ...
};
```